# When did Batman get Kryptonite in Batman v Superman?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

Unless I missed something, in *Batman v Superman*, Batman was chasing the truck with the Kryptonite in, when he then runs into Superman which leads to the “do you bleed?”.

However later on, it shows Batman making Kryptonite bombs ect. When does he get the Kryptonite as he originally looses it in the chase?

Comment: Batman had placed a tracker on the truck before "Do you bleed" scene..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Batman breached LexCorp and stole the Kryptonite

After his failed attempt to capture the Kryptonite, Batman delayed his next move until the attack at the Capitol. This sole event triggered his reaction and immediately after we can see the [following scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SH11CXi61U8), where the box that contained the rock has now a batarang.

The Ultimate Cut of the film, shows us also video footage of Batman attacking the guards before retrieving it.

[image]